# Sorting data in angular 7

Tags: angular, sorting, multilingual, translate

I need to sort labels in angular. I am doing it from the component.ts file. The sorting works fine. It tasks the key value of the label for sorting. But my application is in two languages. so sorting it using key doesn't work when I switch to a different language. Is there a way I can sort it in any language

```
getlabel(Id: string): Observable<Dto[]> {
return this.httpClient
  .get(
    url
  )
  .pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      data.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.label > b.label ? 1 : -1
      })
      return data
    })

  ) as Observable
}
```

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) function:

```
.pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      return data.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.label.localeCompare(b.label, 'he');
      })
    })
  ) as Observable
```

'he' is for Hebrew language, change it to your [language code](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp)

> [Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-list-sort)

Comment: It is Hebrew language

Comment: i have two language en and fr

Comment: Do you know what is the current display language at each time? you write "when I switch to a different language", when you switch the language, save it in a local variable and pass it to localeCompare func

Comment: ok i figured out how to use locale compare to sort in both language , but the sort doesnt happen change until I reload the page. Suppose its english, it sorts and then when i click french it stays with the english sorting until I reload the page

Comment: i think I have to use onLanguagechange but can i use it in service

Comment: This is a bug in your code, I'll update the answer to fix it for you

Comment: And? still no change to the sorted list?

Comment: doesnt sort unless refreshed after lang change

Comment: This is because you're not executing this observable on 'switch language' event. when you switch your language call this function to sort the list with the new language code.

Comment: I'll create a simple demo to show you. How do you "when I switch to a different language", is it with a `select` tag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195617/discussion-between-queue-and-benshabatnoam).

Answer (score 0):

This works for sorting in different languages

```
.pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      data.sort((a, b) => {
        return this.translate
          .instant(a.label)
          .localeCompare(this.translate.instant(b.label))
      })
      return data
    })
  ) as Observable
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pass the key which exists in an input array.

```
function sortByKey(array: [], key: any, sortType = '') {
  if (!array.length) {
     return array;
  }

   return array.sort((a, b) => {
     if (sortType === 'desc') {
          if (b[key] < a[key]) { return -1; }
          if (b[key] > a[key]) { return 1; }
      } else {
          if (a[key] < b[key]) { return -1; }
          if (a[key] > b[key]) { return 1; }
      }

      return 0;
  });
}
```